# Django View Error

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error

```
Django Version:     1.4
Exception Type:     ViewDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

Could not import ratings.views.HotelRating. View does not exist in module ratings.views.
```

but here is my `views.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from ratings.models import Hotel_Rating, Restaurant_Rating, Cafe_Rating, Pastry_Rating
from services.models import *
from ratings.forms import Hotel_Rating_From
from django.template import RequestContext

def HotelRating(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Hotel_Rating_From(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_id = form.cleaned_data['user_id']
            hotel_id = form.cleaned_data['hotel_id']
            user = User.objects.get(id = user_id)
            hotel = Hotel.objects.get(id = hotel_id)
            review = Hotel_Rating(hotel_id = hotel.id, user_id = user.id, overall_rating = form.cleaned_data['overall_rating'], service = form.cleaned_data['service'], cleanliness = form.cleaned_data['cleanliness'], location = form.cleaned_data['location'], rooms = form.cleaned_data['rooms'], restaurant = form.cleaned_data['restaurant'], room_service = form.cleaned_data['room_service'], price = form.cleaned['price'], comment = form.cleaned_data['comment'])
            review.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            form = Hotel_Rating_From(request.POST)
            return render_to_response('hotelreview.html', {'form': form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

and here is my `urls.py` file

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^register/$', 'reviewers.views.ReviewerRegistration'),
    (r'^hotelrating/$', 'ratings.views.HotelRating'),
    (r'^login/$', 'reviewers.views.LoginRequest'),

)
```

I dont know what i did wrong, I have added the ratings app in the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

Comment: functions should start with a lowercase letter http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names. Classes must be camelcased http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names. And is this the ratings/views.py?

Comment: Exception Location:  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in get_callable, line 101

Comment: and @Willian yes it is the ratings/views.py file

Comment: It looks okay at first glance, assuming the app 'ratings' is in the right place. Are you sure 'ratings/views.py' is in the path and not 'myproject/ratings/views.py'? In other words, in Django 1.4 the 'ratings' folder should be one folder up from the project, in the same path as 'manage.py'.

Comment: yes it is in the same path, may be I should delete it and recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a circular import. Move your import statement inside your def to see if that helps.

```
def HotelRating(request):
    from ratings.models import Hotel_Rating
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but it says "View does not exist in module ratings.views."

Answer (score 1):

Have you stripped `ratings/views.py` down to the simplest views file it could be? If you can get it working with a very simple view, work up from there to what you have now.

Also, please consider following [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) when naming your functions (`HotelRating` would become `hotel_rating`) and classes. It will make it easier on anyone you share code with, including this site!

Comment: yes I have even tried it with a simple "pass", but it could not find the view.